# Do Shortcuts inside the Startup folder execute at boot or at logon? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, boot

[microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7) says :

> Programs or shortcuts placed in the Startup folder will run whenever
>   Windows starts

Does that mean that I can boot my machine and not log in to have the program executed or do I need to log in?

Comment: I'm pretty sure only group policies can run before log-on

Comment: When you create a Scheduled Task you have the option for triggers "at logon" or "at Startup". What would be the difference then? Why would they name it the same if it means 2 different things

Comment: @Raystafarian or scheduled tasks, or services (both of which can run without a logged in user).

Comment: @loli Are you asking **because** you want to run a program before login or without being logged in?

Comment: I want to run a .bat without the need of logging in. Just by turning on the computer. I currently do it by scheduled task/windows service, but I can't test my new script because I don't have admin rights. Also when I saw that scheduled tasks had the option "at logon" and "at startup" I wondered if it executed before logon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It starts after **logon**.

---

I think this may be because it needs to start up explorer.exe to find out what is in the start up folder.

---

However you can start **scripts** during the boot more can be read here: http://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/

Comment: but in your link it says : To use the Startup folder to configure a program to run at boot. Does that mean it can run at boot as well from the startup folder? The 2 paragraphs are contradicting themselves...

Comment: There is a startup folder for each user account, so it launches programs at logon of the respective account.

Comment: Are those programs started only the first time the user logs on or every time the user logs on?

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli every time the user logs on